# Encode or Decode space that save in cookies in mvc razor

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, cookies

I am creating cookie using jquery and I set value into it. when I am reading that value, it is coming as something like with %20, there spaces has been converted to some thing like that. so how can I get proper value.

here is my Cookie creation code :

```
 $.cookie('ck_name', 'william smith', { path: '/' });
```

in razor, I am reading cookie like this :

```
 Request.Cookies["ck_coursename"].Value.ToString()
```

Output is : willian%20smith

i tried both @html.raw() and httputility.htmlencode, but problem still persists.

any help ? can be appreciated.. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The value is URL encoded, so you would use the [`UrlDecode` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urldecode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to read it:

```
HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Request.Cookies["ck_coursename"].Value.ToString())
```